# How to keep/assign row & column names when combining 2 vectors into a matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe

**Hello, I'm fairly new to R programming so please don't judge if this seems pretty straightforward.**

I was wondering if there is a way to do the following: I want to combine 2 vectors into an array but keep/assign their column and row names.

My code:

```r
library(ISLR)

mean = sapply(Auto[, 1:3], mean)
sd = sapply(Auto[, 1:3], sd)

mean_sd = matrix(
   data = c(mean, sd),
   nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE
)
```

Printing these individually prints them with their column names as intended.

```
mean
 mpg           cylinders        weight  
 23.445918     104.469388       2977.584184
```

```
sd
 mpg           cylinders        weight 
 7.805007      1.705783         849.402560
```

but printing them combined I get indices and not names.

```
mean_sd
          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 23.445918 5.471939 2977.5842
[2,]  7.805007 1.705783  849.4026
```

Is there a way to get the following:

```
mean_sd
              mpg   cylinders       weight
mean    23.445918    5.471939    2977.5842
sd       7.805007    1.705783     849.4026
```

I searched around a bit and found that I should be using `dimnames(data)` but I couldn't understand how to apply it to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `data.frame()` instead of `matrix()`

```
mean_sd = data.frame(
  mean = sapply(mtcars[, 1:3], mean),
  sd = sapply(mtcars[, 1:3], sd)
)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This will give me the transpose of what i asked but I only need to add `t(mean_sd)` :)

Comment: FYI, adding dimnames to a matrix would go like this: `mean_sd = matrix(
    data = c(mean, sd),
    nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
    dimnames = list(c("mean", "sd"), names(mean))
)`

Comment: @user12728748 this is exactly what i was looking for!! `names(mean)` didn't work but `names(auto[,1:3])` did. Thank you so much!!